# Change the Voice into Passive Voice

Tags: passive-voice

Please turn the below sentences into passive speech
And show how did you do ?

(1)Carry it home
(2) Can anybody Cure it ?
(3) Flowers smell nice
(4) He called it Laurel

Comment: Can you add what you think the correct answers are and why?

Comment: Welcome. Please tell us a bit about how you tried to find the answers to your questions. Also tell us what is the exact problem with changing them into passive voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carry it home:

> Let it be carried home

Can anybody cure it:

> Can it be cured (by anybody)?

Flowers smell nice:

> The flowers smell nice

He called it Lauren:

> It is called Laurel by him